# Solve system of kinematics equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, kinematics

I want to solve the following system for $t_1 + t_2$.

$$ v_f=v_i + a(t_1-t_2) $$ 
$$x_f=x_i+v_i(t_1+t_2)+\frac{1}{2}a(t_1^2−t_2^2)+at_1t_2$$

I've tried solving for $t_1$ and substituting, but the equations get so complex that I don't trust myself to do every step correctly.

Here is the related question on Physics Stackexchange: [How long does it take to optimally change position and velocity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/112687/how-long-does-it-take-to-optimally-change-position-and-velocity)

Comment: Is there a typo perhaps - should the second equation read $$x_f=x_i+v_i(t_1-t_2)+\frac{1}{2}a(t_1^2+t_2^2)-at_1t_2$$?

Comment: I don't think so, no. What gives you that impression though?

Comment: Because if that were the case then the equations would be analogous to standard equations $$v=u+at; s=ut+\frac12at^2$$, where $v=v_f; u=v_i; s=x_f-x_i; t=t_1-t_2$, solving which gives $$v^2=u^2+2as$$ or in this case $$v_f^2=v_i^2+2a(x_f-x_i)$$.

Comment: Ah, I see. The difference is that my system describes an acceleration of $a$ applied for $t_1$ followed by an acceleration of $-a$ applied for $t_2$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Observe that $t_1t_2 = \dfrac{(t_1+t_2)^2-(t_1-t_2)^2}{2}$. Thus this allows you to substitute $u = t_1+t_2, v= t_1-t_2$. Can you continue?

Answer (score 1):

See velocity-time diagram below, based on the original problem statement.

[image]

For the first part of the area under the curve, 
$s_0=\frac12(v_i+v_f)(t_1-t_2) $. 
Also, $v_f=v_i+a(t_1-t_2)$. 
Hence
$$s_0=\frac 12 (v_f+v_i)\frac{v_f-v_i}a=\frac{v_f^2-v_i^2}{2a}$$

The remaining part of the area under the curve is given by
$$v_f(2t_2)+\frac 12 (2t_2)(v_f+at_2)=at_2^2+3v_ft_2$$

The total area under the curve is the total distance travelled, i.e. $x_f-x_i$, hence

$$\begin{align}
s_0+at_2^2+3v_ft_2&=x_f-x_i\\
\frac{v_f^2-v_i^2}{2a}+at_2^2+3v_ft_2&=x_f-x_i\\
at_2^2+3v_ft_2+\frac{v_f^2-v_i^2}{2a}-(x_f-x_i)&=0\\
t_2&=\frac{-3v_f+\sqrt{9v_f^2-4a\left(\frac{v_f^2-v_i^2}{2a}-(x_f-x_i)\right)}}{2a}
\qquad \text{as $t_2>0$}\\
&=\frac{-3v_f+\sqrt{7v_f^2+2v_i^2+4a(x_f-x_i)}}{2a}\\
t_1&=\frac{v_f-v_i}a+t_2\\
&=-\frac{v_i}a+\frac{-v_f+\sqrt{7v_f^2+2v_i^2+4a(x_f-x_i)}}{2a}\\
t_1+t_2&=\frac{-v_i-2v_f+\sqrt{7v_f^2+2v_i^2+4a(x_f-x_i)}}a
\end{align}$$

It does look quite messy. How does it compare with your answer?

Comment: Thank you very much! However, it looks like your final equation can return complex values if $x_f - x_i$ is a large negative number.

Comment: Yes that's true. Which other approach have you tried?

Comment: I'm not sure of the mathematics, but if you return the absolute difference instead, the resulting heuristic performs quite admirably. Here are two paths: http://i.imgur.com/AbekE4L.gif http://i.imgur.com/TXynyEg.gif